# Multiple pins on MKMapview

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

Is it possible to add multiple pins on MKmapview?.I have added one and done the annotation,Am looking to add multiple pins on MKMapview.Pls help me out.

Comment: Yes it's possible.  What's the exact problem or error you have?  What have you tried?  Show how you added the single annotation.

Comment: I give the code below to show my annotation method.

Comment: DDAnnotation *annotation = [[[DDAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:theCoordinate addressDictionary:nil] autorelease];
 DDAnnotation *annotation1 = [[[DDAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:theCoordinate addressDictionary:nil] autorelease];
 
 annotation.title = @"Location";
 annotation1.title = @"Location";
 annotation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f %f", annotation.coordinate.latitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude];
 annotation1.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f %f", annotation1.coordinate.latitude, annotation.

Answer (score 7):

Just simply use the [mapView addAnnotations:] instead of addAnnotation.
You'll have to provide an Array of your annotations for it.

Comment: Or just call addAnnotation multiple times.

Comment: I have tried callingh it multiple times.It doesn work.any more help pls

Answer (score 0):

///  ExplainClass is new class in which have declare  cordinate,tittle,sutitle

ExplainClass

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate; 
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title; 
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
```

//  MapClass

```
 MKMapView *mapView;
        MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0} };
        region.center.latitude = 22.569722 ;
        region.center.longitude = 88.369722;
        region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
        region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
        [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    MKCoordinateRegion region1 = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0} };
    region1.center.latitude = 37.786996 ;
    region1.center.longitude = -122.419281;
    region1.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region1.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    [mapView setRegion:region1 animated:YES];


    [mapView setDelegate:self];



    ExplainClass *ann = [[ExplainClass alloc] init]; 
    ann.title = @" Kolkata";
    ann.subtitle = @"Mahatma Gandhi Road"; 
    ann.coordinate = region.center; 

   ExplainClass *ann1 = [[ExplainClass alloc] init];
    ann.title = @" Abc";
    ann.subtitle = @"Road";
    ann.coordinate = region1.center;



    [mapView addAnnotation:ann];
    [mapView addAnnotation:ann1];
```

Comment: Really nicely presented code above. The breakdown really help me in understanding the functionality quickly. However to improve on the answer, what i did was to have an array with the lat/long. Then I ran the above code in a for loop iterating through my lat/long array. That made sure there wasn't any duplication of the code like it is above with variables "region" and "ann"